# Do jets use tinted windows?

Tags: aircraft-design, windows

For cars, I've heard of LLumar used as window tint.
Do jet aircraft use window tint? If so, what type of window tint do they use?

Comment: `Like any specifics` I don't know what this means.  Is there an alternative phrase that you could use?

Comment: I guess the OP wants to know if jets use window tint, (no they don't) and if they do, which brand of tint specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, airplanes (all types including jets) can use window tints.

**Ultraviolet "A"**
Tints for airplanes are with enhanced protection from UVA radiation. UVA exposure can increase the risk of skin cancer and will damage most organic materials. Its intensity increases about 5% with every 1000 feet of altitude. Unlike car tints, airplane tints need to block the additional exposure to UVA.

**Solar Energy Control**
Tints also block near-infrared radiation which results in lesser interior heat.

LP Aero Plastics ([product listing](http://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/appages/lpaero.php)) and [PolyOne](http://www.sdplastics.com/polycastaerospaceacrylicsheet.html) are the two manufactures I found for aircraft tints.