# Do any aircraft windshields have anti-reflective coatings?

Tags: safety, windows, visibility, windscreen, canopy

Anti-reflective coatings are used in many applications to reduce glare and prevent double images.  Double images in particular are a concern because of the several layers involved in a cockpit window.  More high-tech optical coatings can also have other desirable properties such as reducing UV and IR light transmission. There is some evidence of them being used in industry, like this [patent for a windscreen](http://www.google.com/patents/US4932608). On a related note, cockpit instruments have a limit for maximum reflectivity of their glass/plastic surface and sometimes use anti-reflective coatings.

I started thinking about this because of a recent question on [why windscreens aren't *more* reflective](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30573/why-dont-aircraft-commercial-and-military-use-reflective-visor-windshields).

However, I can't find many examples of anti-reflective coatings (possibly because of the harsh environmental conditions?).  UV and IR protection seem to be mostly through [tinting](http://www.polyone.com/products/cast-acrylic/aerospace-cast-acrylic/polycast-uv-sc-uv-blocking-solar-heat-control-cell) instead of coating.

Do any production aircraft use anti-reflective or other coatings?  Why or why not?

Comment: [It looks like one of the windows on this 787 is reflective coated](http://www.engadget.com/2013/03/25/boeing-787-dreamliner-functional-flight-check/)

Comment: Some military aircraft have a gold coatings from what I know.

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes, good find.  The 787 seem to have a gold-based heating film that also serves to block infared light: http://www.aerospacemanufacturinganddesign.com/article/aerospace-manufacturing-design-boeing-ppg-787-amd/

Comment: @SMSvonderTann I'm familiar only with the F-16 "Have Glass" golden coating designed to reflect radar.  If you have any good sources, go ahead and put them as an answer.

Comment: Related questions for [fighter jet canopy materials](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21802/1696), [tinted windows](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26610/1696).

Comment: I am not sure but almost anything reflects light (even dust in air reflect light), even just a little bit. So a coating always reflects some light away which making it not so possible to make something anti-reflective. The work should be done on the glass itself to make it less reflective overall.

Comment: @Hezzte You seem to misunderstand how anti-reflective coatings work. I'd suggest you read up some on them before speculating.  Anti-reflective coatings have been around for over a century and are used on many glasses, and are even listed in the patent I linked in my question.  This is not novel or extraordinary technology by any means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[An antireflective coating for the F/A-18's canopy was successfully tested sometime in the 1990s](https://sbirsource.com/sbir/awards/20387-durable-anti-reflective-coating-for-the-f-18-windshield); no word on whether it made it into production, though.

Wikipedia [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockpit#Ergonomics) that "[n]early all glass windows in large aircraft have an anti-reflective coating", but provides no source for this assertion.